# Best way to get a number from a range?

Tags: math

This is a little more math orientated but I would like to know the best way to do the following;

```
min = 20;
max = 80;
```

Given a number 1 through x, what is the best way to linearly distribute these numbers evenly?

For example when `n=1` value is always min, when `n=x`, value is always max so 80 in this case.

When `n=x/2` value is 35 (mid point between min and max)

If this were to be a function like `double getNum(min, max, x, n)` which returns the value of the number between min/max, what would be the best way to write this?

Comment: Sorry for the wording, this was difficult to conceptualise

Comment: Given that you want ints, the best answer depends on how you want the rounding to work, which in turn depends on what you want to use these numbers for. What do you want to use these numbers for?

Comment: Doesn't necessarily need to be rounded actually, can be a decimal number.

Comment: While I'm at it, is there an actual name a function like this has? Someone has to have done this before right?

Comment: Dunno about a specific name, but it's definitely been done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple to derive the following formula:

```
double nth(double min, double max, int n, int x) {
    return min + (max-min) * ((double) n-1) / (x-1);
}
```

Comment: Why does nth(1, 100, 5, 10); output 45 instead of 50?

Comment: @user1008134: Because the steps are 1, 12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78, 89, 100. If you expected 50, you have a fencepost error. Perhaps you want `n` to start at 0, rather than 1? (If you do, you'll also need to change your call to `nth(0, 100, 5, 10)`, as well as changing the logic inside `nth`.)

Comment: Ah I see, your implentation is correct then. Thanks!